# How to make a "swipe up" function like in many custom launchers?

Tags: java, android, launcher

I'm doing my own custom launcher for Android at the moment. Everything works so far. But there is one point where I need help.
I would like to do something like a swipe up on the home screen to display all installed apps. Therefore I do not want to start a new activity, cause of the delay.
Maybe it's possible to change the layout file with something like an animation when a gesture is detected? And how would I detect the swipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy to detect motion:

```
someViewLikeLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //put finger on screen
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //release the finger
                    return true;

            }

        }
    });
```

Just switch `event` and you can get many actions via `MotionEvent`
Good luck!